# how to retrieve all the relevant records for the employee id in mysql

Tags: php

Am trying to print all the records mapped for the eid, but am getting error and unexpected end of file.
    
     '
     + '
     font-weight: bold; border: 1 solid #0000FF" '
     + 'onClick="javascript:window.print()"> </form>');
     }
      // End hide -->

```
  <?php

  //$v1=$_GET['id'];
  //echo $v1;
  $con = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");
  if(!$con)
   {
    die("connection failed:".mysql_error());
       }
     $eeid=$_GET['id'];
    $sql="select * from employee where eid=$eeid";
      $rs=mysql_query($sql);

     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
     $eid = $row['id'];
     $ename = $row['name'];
     $edesign=$row['designation'];

       <tr>
           <td><p align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="2"           
        color="#0000FF">&nbsp;<? echo $eid; ?>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><p align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="2"           
        color="#0000FF">&nbsp;<? echo $ename; ?>&nbsp;</td>

     <td><p align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="2"        
     color="#0000FF">&nbsp;<? echo $edesign; ?>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><p align="center">
     <form name="errorpage" metho="POST" action ="emplyee.php">
     Enter the emp  code : <input type="text" name="id">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Lock">
     </form>
     </td> 
     </tr>
      }
     mysql_close();
     ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: just so you know, you cant mix php and html like that, you have to stop php `?>` before you start using html.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing endings to the php. The html will not run in a php script without them

```
  //$v1=$_GET['id'];
  //echo $v1;
 $con = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");
 if(!$con)
 {
die("connection failed:".mysql_error());
   }
 $eeid=$_GET['id'];
$sql="select * from employee where eid=$eeid";
  $rs=mysql_query($sql);

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
 $eid = $row['id'];
 $ename = $row['name'];
 $edesign=$row['designation'];
 ?>
   <tr>
       <td><p align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="2"           
    color="#0000FF">&nbsp;<? echo $eid; ?>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><p align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="2"           
    color="#0000FF">&nbsp;<? echo $ename; ?>&nbsp;</td>

 <td><p align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="2"        
 color="#0000FF">&nbsp;<? echo $edesign; ?>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><p align="center">
 <form name="errorpage" metho="POST" action ="emplyee.php">
 Enter the emp  code : <input type="text" name="id">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Lock">
 </form>
 </td> 
 </tr>
 <?php
  }
 mysql_close();
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Try this

Comment: I tried but error am getting as parse error syntax error unexpected. }in line38